# R How to split a string

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a string like

```
a <- "Hi. I m cool, but I need help!"
```

And as an output i would like to have

```
"hi" "." "I" "m" "cool" "," "but" "I" "need" "help" "!"
```

Furthermore I don't want to use extra packages.

Comment: What is the logic? Split at every non-word character? And what logic to get "hi" from "Hi ..."?

Comment: could you use just this code: `yourString.split(" ")`. I'm not a R developer but most languages got a function like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
a1 <- strsplit(a, '\\s|(?=[!,.])\\s*', perl = TRUE)[[1]]
a1[nzchar(a1)]
#[1] "Hi"   "."    "I"    "m"    "cool" ","    "but"  "I"    "need" "help" "!"
```